# mutableCopy and ARC causing me memory issues?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tagsList;
```

and I assign it like this:

```
self.tagsList = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:tagRequest error:&tagerror] mutableCopy];
```

I am brand new to using ARC and this was a converted project.  From what I have read it seems this kind of behavior could me the cause of some memory problems I am having.

Is this the case here?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the memory problems?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem regarding memory here. Can you explain your question more?

Comment: You should profile your application in instruments to determine if you're having memory problems, but I really doubt this call would be the cause of it. The fetch request will load the objects into memory, and doing a mutable copy of the array isn't going to duplicate those objects or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's exactly what ARC is good for. You don't have to care about releasing that copy.